# Прокрутка элементов по оси

Tags: javascript

Нужно в течении 7 секунд прокрутить круги по оси и постепенно с каждой секундой снижать скорость движения к нулю.

Изначально все нормально движется, но к концу времени элементы заезжают друг на друга.

```
function loop() {

    step = 1 / 60;
    speed -= step;

    if(speed <= 0) clearInterval(interval);
    for(var i = 0; i < angles.length; i++) {

        angle = angles[i].angle;

        x = cx + radius * Math.cos(angle * deg2rad);
        y = cy + radius * Math.sin(angle * deg2rad);

        $('.div').eq(i).css({left:x - radiusSat, top:y - radiusSat});

        angles[i].angle = angles[i].angle + speed;
        if (angles[i].angle > 360) angles[i].angle = 0;
    }
}
```

Подробнее https://jsfiddle.net/bgntx9j1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (angles[i].angle > 360) angles[i].angle = angles[i].angle - 360;
```

В последней строке код как привел я. У вас не настолько мелкое значение, чтоб списывать его в 0. Вот и наезжает:)
Фиддл: https://jsfiddle.net/L5sbnmoq/

Comment: черт круто, не додумался благодарю, как тут спасибо сказать)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow rus:)